# How to save upload files to outside of Rails application folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wan't to save my uploaded image outside of Rails(3) application. As I'm developing 2 separate application, but those applications are sharing same database. So I need a folder from where I can access images from both application.

Comment: use C.D.N like [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) or [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a symbolic link to the shared folder in your public folder for both apps, then it will appear to be in the public folder for both apps.

eg, in the terminal, in your rails project folder

```
ln -s /path/to/your/shared/folder public/shared
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux I've seen people using ["symbolic links"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) for this. A concept not unlike Windows *shortcuts*, it looks like a folder, it quacks like a folder but is actually a link to a folder somewhere else.

```
ln -s target_path link_path
```

You could create a *special folder* somewhere and then create symbolic links inside both apps' folders to point to that *special folder*.

A similar trick is used by [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) in order to maintain some of the files between different versions of the application.